Double Integral Problem in Polar Coordinates
How do I solve this integral? I have tried adding and subtracting $\left(R \cos \phi\right)$ so that I can take denominator as the new term and use it in the iterated integral of $r$, splitting the integral into two and integrating them separately to get the answer $8-3\pi $. However I am afraid I might be wrong, this integral is actually part of an electrostatics problem and I am not getting the required answer.
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^R \frac{r d r d \phi}{\left(R^2+r^2+2 R r \cos \phi\right)^{1 / 2}}
$$

This is likely to be almost the same problem that I solved here.

$$\int_0^R \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+2 r R \cos (\phi )+R^2}} \, dr=R \left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos (\phi )+1}-\cos (\phi ) \log \left(\sqrt{\sec ^2\left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)}+1\right)-1\right)$$
$$\int_0^{2 \pi } R \left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\cos (\phi )+1}-\cos (\phi ) \log \left(\sqrt{\sec ^2\left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)}+1\right)-1\right) \, d\phi=4 R$$

Could you please elaborate on the steps you have used, maybe what substitutions you have done to get from one step to the next.
